# How can I predict model from Handwriting numbers?

Tags: python, arrays, google-colaboratory, training-data, predict

I collected Handwriting number and train model with VGG16
and made model is Sequential

```
from keras import models
from keras import layers
from keras import optimizers

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu', input_dim=7 * 7 * 512))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(layers.Dense(63, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer= tensorflow.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=2e-4),
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['acc'])
```

I save in name modeldata.h5 and load it.

```
# load the handwriting OCR model
from keras.models import load_model
args = {}
args["model"] = '/content/drive/MyDrive/project/modeldata.h5'
model = load_model(args["model"] )
```

This is my model.summary()

[image]

Then I want to predict Image of number 8.

```
from tensorflow.keras.utils import load_img
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = '/content/drive/MyDrive/project/Dataset/DATA3/78/78_10.png'
image= cv2.imread(img)
cv2_imshow(image)
```

[image]
And predict it

```
plt.imshow(image.reshape(224, 224),cmap='Greys')
pred = model.predict(image.reshape(1, 224, 224, 1))
print("From which the max choice is:", pred.argmax())
```

This is an error
[image]

please Help me to fix it! I have model but I don't know to predict the numbers.
I want resault is my model can predicted this picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here actually there are many problems. The 2 major problems are:

1. Why is your input_dim=7 * 7 * 512? I see you want to reshape your image to 224, 224 then your input_dim should be 224*224.
2. You can't just reshape your image to 224x224, you need to resize it. You can do that with cv2.resize, here are some examples: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/image-resizing-using-opencv-python/

Edit:
Adding solution.
In your case you can do something like this:

```
image = cv2.imread(img)
image = cv2.resize(image, (224, 224))
image = image[None, ...]

features = vgg_conv.predict(image)
features = np.reshape(features,(1,7*7*512))
result = model.predict(features)
```

Comment: How can I reshape of image 224,224 to 7*7*512?

Comment: I pretrain with VGG16 that why i use  input_dim=7 * 7 * 512. But I confuse Input shape of VGG16 is 224,224,3 but my model is not, How can I reshap image to fit my input model?

Comment: Share your entire model first, I don't see VGG16 anywhere.

Comment: I write entire model in the answer below.

Comment: So, you have 2 models, one for feature extracting and another for classification. Actually you should have combined them into one. But it's ok, now you need to resize your image to (224,224) then supply it into VGG16 to get the features, then you can reshape your features to 7*7*512.

Comment: Could you please write the code. I'm so confuse about the variable. please TT

Comment: I added a possible solution.